# standard error of addition, subtraction, multiplication and ratio

Tags: statistics, prediction, confidence-interval, standard-error

Let's say, I have two random variables,x and y, both of them have n observations. I've used a forecasting method to estimate xn+1 and yn+1, and I also got the standard error for both xn+1 and yn+1. So my question is that what the formula would be if I want to know the standard error of xn+1 + yn+1, xn+1 - yn+1, (xn+1)*(yn+1) and (xn+1)/(yn+1), so that I can calculate the prediction interval for the 4 combinations. Any thought would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the general topic you need to look at is called "change of variables" in mathematical statistics.

The density function for a sum of random variables is the convolution of the individual densities (but only if the variables are independent). Likewise for the difference. In special cases, that convolution is easy to find. For example, for Gaussian variables the density of the sum is also a Gaussian.

For product and quotient, there aren't any simple results, except in special cases. For those, you might as well compute the result directly, maybe by sampling or other numerical methods.

If your variables x and y are not independent, that complicates the situation. But even then, I think sampling is straightforward.